# Is there a way to send firebase web push notification from the firebase console

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I think the firebase console can only send notifications to android and IOS app not to web browser, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) supports Android, iOS, and Web apps.

> The FCM JavaScript API lets you receive notification messages in web apps running in browsers that support the Push API.

Here's the [official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).

But you have to know that some browsers doesn't support Push API.

[Can I use: Push API support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api)

Comment: Thanks for your answer what I want to know is if there is a way to send push notification to the browsers from the firebase console without writing backend code to send the notification.

Comment: When I open the firebase console I can only send notifications to the IOS and Android but for the web I can only send by using the FCM Api.